# Как в современных форумных движках реализован механизм новых сообщений?

Tags: база-данных, форум

Т.е. пользователю подсвечиваются названия тем, в которых появились новые сообщения с момента его последнего визита. ЗЫ. Пока самым (если не единственным) решением вижу сохранять в таблице `user_id`, `post_id` и `timestamp` последнего просмотра.

Comment: Имеются ввиду форумные движки.

Comment: Добавил за вас это уточнение в вопрос. Вы кстати можете и сами править/уточнять вопросы.

Comment: А зачем на других смотреть. тем более что особо ничего другого не придумаешь. дату последнего просмотра надо хранить, остается вопрос где: в БД на сервере под пользователя (что делать с анонимами ?), в куках браузера (проблемы с анонимами нет, но заход с другого браузера или устройства - свой отсчет), смешанные варианты, типа нет куки - берем из БД

Comment: @Mike , значит предложенный мной вариант и есть оптимальный?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что он единственный. По крайней мере мне в голову ничего другого не приходит ... Мне вот правда анонимные пользователи покоя не дают. Для них либо не давать такой информации в принципе, либо идентифицировать браузер (например по кукам) и делать эдакого "виртуального" пользователя

Comment: И учитывая что вы хотите по каждой теме отдельно, гнать эту информацию в браузер и хранить там явно не подходит, тем то вагон.